# If some non-primitive polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, does this imply it is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I know from a lemma in Herstein that if a primitive polynomial in $R[x]$ is irreducible in its field of quotients $F[x]$, then it is irreducible in $R[x]$.

But, if some **non**-primitive polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, does this imply the **non**-primitive polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition an element $f$ of a ring $R$ is irreducible if whenever $f=uv$ for $u,v\in R$, either $u$ or $v$ is a unit.

By definition if $f$ is nonprimitive in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, $f=ng(x)$ where $n$ is the gcd of it's coefficients, which is not $\pm 1$, and hence not a unit, and $g(x)$ is a primitive polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ of positive degree and hence not a unit. Thus regardless of whether or not $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, it is reducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Note that the constant becomes a unit in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, so it doesn't matter there, but it does matter in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.