# Generalization of Murty's Irreducibility Criterion

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am reading the paper "[On an irreducibility criterion of M. Ram Murty](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.2005.11920194)" by Kurt Girstmair.

I have a question regarding an assumption of the proof, which I have stated at the end of the post.

**Theorem:**
Let $f(x)=a_mx^m+\cdots+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ be a primitive polynomial of
degree $m \ge 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and set $H$ as
$$
 H:=\operatorname{max}_{0 \ \le i\le \ m-1} \left|\frac{a_i}{a_m}\right|
 $$
If for some natural number $d$ , $n$ and a prime $p$ we have
$$
f(n)=\pm d.p \ \ \ \ \ 
; \ \ \ \ \ H+d+1 \le n
 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  p \ \ \text{does not divide} \ \  d 
$$

then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

**Proof:**

**1.**
$f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are of positive degree.
$$
   f(n)=g(n)h(n)=\pm d\cdot p \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ 
   p \nmid d
   $$
One of the factors $g(n)$ or $h(n)$ cannot divisible by $p$, and therefore must divide $d$. WLOG we assume $g(n) \mid d$

**2.**
Now we know that $g(x)$ is of the form
$$g(x)=c \prod_i (x-\alpha_i)$$
where $c$ : leading coefficient of $g \ \ $ & $\ \ \alpha_i$ runs over a subset of zeros of $f$.

**3.** For each root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ we have
$$
 \mathbf{\mid n- \alpha \mid} 
 \ge 
 n-|\alpha| \ \ 
 > \ \ 
 H+d+1-(H+1)=\mathbf{d}
 $$
Therefore we contradict the fact $\ \ g(n) \mid d \ \ $ as
$$
 \mathbf{|g(n)|}
 =|c| \prod_i |n-\alpha_i| \ \ 
 \mathbf{> \ d}
 $$

Hence we arrive at a contradiction.

---

**My Question:**

Where are we using the fact that $f$ is a primitive polynomial?

Comment: It might be there just because if it is not primitive, then it is trivially reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ (see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290602))